# unrecognized option '-tree-vectorize

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, assembly

I have the following error

```
make all 
Building file: ../src/asm.S
Invoking: GCC Assembler
arm-linux-gnueabi-as  -mcpu=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon   -mfloat-abi=softfp  -ftree- vectorize  -o "src/asm.o" "../src/asm.S"
arm-linux-gnueabi-as: unrecognized option '-tree-vectorize'
make: *** [src/asm.o] Error 1
```

while compiling FFMpeg code for fourier transform code using .S files which include VFP commands

the options used in compiler:

Commands in Build C/C++ settings section
GCC C Compiler :
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -O3 -S -mcpu=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon  -ffast-math  -mfloat-abi=softfp

GCC C Linker:
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon  -ffast-math -ftree-vectorize -mthumb -mfloat-abi=softfp

GCC Assembler
arm-linux-gnueabi-as  -mcpu=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon   -mfloat-abi=softfp  -ftree-vectorize

I am using Eclipse.

Thanks in advance for your help.
Mahmoud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-ftree- vectorize` is a **gcc** option used for automatic vectorization of C and C++ code. You shouldn't (can't) use it on **as**.

Comment: Ok, so if i have .S file, no i choose only to add neon, cortex1-8 options, errors : function fft4_neon appear